# How would I decode this example?

Tags: swift, codable

We are having difficulty decoding an element coming in JSON using the codable protocol on Swift 5:

```
"expiration": 1620975599000,
```

Have tried to convert it to Int64, String and Double, every time we get a crazy small number.  Noticing that the value is not in quotes, so string is problematic.  What data type would this convert to?   (It is supposed to be a millisecond timestamp)

Comment: I tried with a Double and I got `1620975599000.0`. So how do you have that "crazy small number"? But if you set your Codable property as `Date`, you can use `decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .millisecondsSince1970` and it will be done itself.

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to decode the number into, a `Date` object?

Comment: I suspect your problem is elsewhere in your code. If you simplify to just an object with this one field, I expect will works without trouble. (This number fits easily into an Int on 64-bit platforms, and an Int64 on 32-bit platforms.)